# Ansible: mysql_user not working for non-root user

Tags: mysql, ansible, mariadb

I'm trying to setup a simple Ansible script to setup a MariaDB installation. However for some reason, I can change the root user's password fine, login as root with the new password on the next run fine, create a database fine, but if I try to use `mysql_user` on any other user, it always fails.

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  remote_user: centos
  vars:
    rootpwd: Password1
    replipwd: Password2
    dbname: tests
  tasks:
  - name: Installing packages
    yum: name={{item}} state=latest
    with_items:
     - mariadb
     - mariadb-server
     - mariadb-devel
  - name: Installing Python module
    pip: name=MySQL-python
  - name: Server configuration
    lineinfile: dest=/etc/my.cnf line={{ item }} mode=0644 create=yes
    with_items:
    - bind-address=0.0.0.0
    - log-bin
    - server_d={{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0].split('.')[3] }}
    - log-basename=log{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0].split('.')[3] }}
  - name: Restarting services
    service: state=restarted name=mariadb enabled=yes
  - name: Securing root account
    mysql_user: name=root password={{ rootpwd }} priv=*.*:ALL state=present
  - name: Client configuration
    lineinfile: dest=/root/.my.cnf line={{ item }} mode=0600 create=yes
    with_items:
    - "[client]"
    - user=root
    - password={{ rootpwd }}
  - name: Making database
    mysql_db: name={{ dbname }} state=present
  - name: Making replication user
    mysql_user: name=replicate password={{ replipwd }} priv="*.*:REPLICATION SLAVE" state=present host="%"
```

Run:

```
...
TASK [Restarting services] *****************************************************
task path: /home/centos/.ansible/centos-mariadb.playbook:25
changed: [172.30.1.21] => {"changed": true, "enabled": true, "name": "mariadb", "state": "started"}
changed: [172.30.1.38] => {"changed": true, "enabled": true, "name": "mariadb", "state": "started"}

TASK [Securing root account] ***************************************************
task path: /home/centos/.ansible/centos-mariadb.playbook:27
ok: [172.30.1.38] => {"changed": false, "user": "root"}
ok: [172.30.1.21] => {"changed": false, "user": "root"}

TASK [Client configuration] ****************************************************
task path: /home/centos/.ansible/centos-mariadb.playbook:30
ok: [172.30.1.21] => (item=[client]) => {"backup": "", "changed": false, "item": "[client]", "msg": ""}
ok: [172.30.1.38] => (item=[client]) => {"backup": "", "changed": false, "item": "[client]", "msg": ""}
ok: [172.30.1.21] => (item=user=root) => {"backup": "", "changed": false, "item": "user=root", "msg": ""}
ok: [172.30.1.38] => (item=user=root) => {"backup": "", "changed": false, "item": "user=root", "msg": ""}
ok: [172.30.1.21] => (item=password=Password1) => {"backup": "", "changed": false, "item": "password=Password1", "msg": ""}
ok: [172.30.1.38] => (item=password=Password1) => {"backup": "", "changed": false, "item": "password=Password1", "msg": ""}

TASK [Making database] *********************************************************
task path: /home/centos/.ansible/centos-mariadb.playbook:36
ok: [172.30.1.21] => {"changed": false, "db": "tests"}
ok: [172.30.1.38] => {"changed": false, "db": "tests"}

TASK [Making replication user] *************************************************
task path: /home/centos/.ansible/centos-mariadb.playbook:38
fatal: [172.30.1.21]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "(1045, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)\")"}
fatal: [172.30.1.38]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "(1045, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)\")"}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
```

Connecting manually from the shell works fine:

```
$ sudo mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 6
Server version: 5.5.50-MariaDB MariaDB Server
```

Comment: Could you rephrase the problem description in simple English?

Comment: I cannot use the mysql_user to create any user, always getting a login failed error, even though I know the credentials are working?

Answer (score 1):

After losing many hours I finally fixed it. Turns out that this line has 3 bugs in it:

```
- name: Securing root account
  mysql_user: name=root password={{ rootpwd }} priv=*.*:ALL state=present host=localhost
```

First, you would think `priv` would give root all accesses, but it actually removes `GRANT` access, so you cannot create new users from then on. Also, you would think this restricts access to only localhost, but it actually creates a new root user with access to localhost. Finally, you would think that you're changing the password for root, but you're only setting it for the one user you just created from localhost. There are still 4 more root users with empty passwords.

This is what I ended up having to do:

```
- name: Securing root account
  mysql_user: name=root password={{ rootpwd }} state=present host=localhost
- name: Remove anonymous users
  raw: mysql -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='';"
- name: Set root permission
  raw: mysql -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root' AND host!='localhost';"
```